# Binding recursive treeView

Tags: c#, ado.net, linq-to-entities, treeview

I'm developping a Windows Form application on Visual Sudio and this is the my first time with treeView. My project has a ADO .NET entity data model of and SQL database, I have 3 tables with relations:

- `Category` (`idCategory, nameCategory`)
- `subCategory` (`idSubCategory, nameSubCategorie, idCategory`)
- `Articles` (`idArticle, nameArticle, idSubCategory`)

I'm trying to create a treeView with recursion from this database to finally get a result like below, I'm stuck here someone can help me please?
Here is what I want to show:

```
+Category1
   +subCategory1-1
      article1
      article2
      article3
   +subCategory1-2
      article1
      article2
      article3
   +subCategory1-3
      article1
      article2
      article3
+Category2
   +subCategory2-1
      article1
      article2
      article3
   +subCategory2-2
      article1
      article2
      article3
   +subCategory2-3
      article1
      article2
      article3
```

A template code for binding recursive treeView from database usinf LINQ or a tutorial link that shows how to do that will be very helpfull! Thanks.

Comment: are you using the database to populate your three tables??

Comment: those tables are in a sql db.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, here I am populating the three tables in my code only, you can get that directly from the database also...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Bind();
        }
    }
    public void Bind()
    {
        DataTable dt = Get_Category();
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
            node.Text = dt.Rows[i]["idCategory"].ToString();
            node.Value = dt.Rows[i]["nameCategory"].ToString();
            AddSubCategory(node);
            this.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        }
    }
    public void AddSubCategory(TreeNode node)
    {
        DataRow[] datarows = Get_SubCategory()
                             .Select("idCategory='" + node.Value + "'");
        foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            TreeNode childnode = new TreeNode();
            childnode.Text = dr["nameSubCategory"].ToString();
            childnode.Value = dr["idSubCategory"].ToString();
            AddArticles(childnode);
            node.ChildNodes.Add(childnode);
        }
    }
    public void AddArticles(TreeNode node)
    {
        DataRow[] datarows = Get_Articles()
                            .Select("idSubCategory='" + no.Value + "'");
        foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
        {
            TreeNode childnode = new TreeNode();
            childnode.Text = dr["Subject"].ToString();
            childnode.Value = dr["SubjectID"].ToString();
            node.ChildNodes.Add(childnode);
        }
    }
    public DataTable Get_Category()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        string IDs = "1,2,3,4";
        string categories = "Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4";
        string[] list1 = IDs.Split(',');
        string[] list2 = categories.Split(',');
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nameCategory"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idCategory"));
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["idCategory"] = list1[i];
            dr["nameCategory"] = list2[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public DataTable Get_SubCategory()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
        string subCategories = "SubCategory1, SubCategory2, SubCategory3, 
                                SubCategory4, SubCategory5, SubCategory6, 
                                SubCategory7, SubCategory8, SubCategory9";
        string idCategory = "1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1";
        string[] list1 = IDs.Split(',');
        string[] list2 = subCategories.Split(',');
        string[] list3 = idCategory.Split(',');
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nameSubCategory"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idSubCategory"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idCategory"));
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["idSubCategory"] = list1[i];
            dr["nameSubCategory"] = list2[i];
            dr["idCategory"] = list3[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public DataTable Get_Articles()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr;
        string IDs = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13";
        string articles = "Articles1, Articles2, Articles3,Articles4, 
                           Articles5, Articles6, Articles7, Articles8, 
                           Articles9, Articles10, Articles11, Articles12, 
                           Articles13";
        string idSubCategory = "8,2,9,2,7,2,3,4,1,5,6,7,1";
        string[] list1 = IDs.Split(',');
        string[] list2 = articles.Split(',');
        string[] list3 = idSubCategory.Split(',');
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("nameArticle"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idArticle"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("idSubCategory"));
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["idArticle"] = list1[i];
            dr["nameArticle"] = list2[i];
            dr["idSubCategory"] = list3[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I m analizing this i will give a response as soos as i finish.

Comment: ".Value" and ".chidNodes" are underlined by the red Line.. A directive is missing...?

Comment: Can you tell me in which line its giving an error, if directive is missing then you can use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode`

Comment: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode` is not recognized... I'm working on windows form with framework 4.0

Comment: check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.100).aspx , might be this will help you for windows form

Comment: "ChildNodes" is for Webforms! It's just "Nodes" in windows forms.

Comment: so instead of ChildNodes add Nodes and see whats u r getting??